# Remove nodes with given key in linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I'm having a hard time figuring out what is wrong with my code. I'm suppose to remove all nodes containing the specific item. In the test code below my code, it requires me to remove all the items "to" in the sentence "to be or not to be" and then return the head, which in this case is "be". Can someone please point out the problem with my code? Thank you.

```
package edu.csc130.assignment;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ListStackQueue {
/**
 * @param head the head of the input linked list
 * @param item the given value
 * @return the head of the linked list with nodes contains the given value removed
 * Assume for any node in the  linked list, node.item cannot be null
 */
  public static Node<String> removeNodes(Node<String> head, String item) {
    Node<String> curr = head;
    Node<String> prev = null;

    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("list is empty");
    } else {
        while (curr != null) {
            if (curr.data != item) {
                prev = curr; 
                curr = curr.next; 
            } else if (curr == head && curr.data == item) {
                head = head.next; 
                curr = curr.next; 
            } else if (curr != head && curr.next != null && curr.data == item) {
                prev.next = curr.next; 
                curr = curr.next; 
            } else {
                curr.next = null; 
            }
        }   
    }

    return head;
  }
}
```

BuildList Part of Code <--I apologize, I did not put up this part of the code. Thanks to those who have helped me so far.

```
/**
 * @param items input array
 * @return the first node of the linked list build from the input array
 */
public static <E> Node<E>  buildList(E[] items) {
    Node<E> head = null;
    if (items!=null && items.length>0) {
        head = new Node<E> (items[0], null);
        Node<E> tail = head;
        for (int i=1; i<items.length; i++) {
            tail.next = new Node<E>(items[i], null);
            tail = tail.next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}

/**
 * @param head the first node of the linked list
 * @return the length of the linked list
 */
public static <E> int getLength(Node<E> head) {
    int length = 0;
    Node<E> node = head;
    while (node!=null) {
        length++;
        node = node.next;
    }
    return length;
}

public static <E> E get(Node<E> head, int index) {
    E item = null;
    Node<E> node = head;
    for (int i=0; i<index; i++) {
        if (node != null) {
            node = node.next;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (node!=null) {
        item = node.item;
    }
    return item;
}

public static class Node<E> {
    public Object data;

    public String data();
    E item;
    Node<E> next;

    public Node(E item) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(E item, Node<E> next) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

The test code:

```
package edu.csc130.assignment;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import edu.csc130.assignment.ListStackQueue.Node;

public class ListStackQueueTest {

  @Test
  public void testRemoveNodes1() {
    Node<String> head = ListStackQueue.buildList(null);
    ListStackQueue.removeNodes(head, "to");
    Assert.assertNull(head);
  }

  @Test
  public void testRemoveNodes2() {
    String[] sentence = {"to", "be", "or", "not", "to", "be"};
    Node<String> head = ListStackQueue.buildList(sentence);
    head = ListStackQueue.removeNodes(head, "to");
    Assert.assertEquals(4, ListStackQueue.getLength(head));
    Assert.assertEquals("be", ListStackQueue.get(head, 0));
    Assert.assertEquals("or", ListStackQueue.get(head, 1));
    Assert.assertEquals("not", ListStackQueue.get(head, 2));
    Assert.assertEquals("be", ListStackQueue.get(head, 3));
  } 

  @Test
  public void testRemoveNodes3() {
    String[] sentence = {"to", "be", "or", "not", "to", "be"};
    Node<String> head = ListStackQueue.buildList(sentence);
    head = ListStackQueue.removeNodes(head, "be");
    Assert.assertEquals(4, ListStackQueue.getLength(head));
    Assert.assertEquals("to", ListStackQueue.get(head, 0));
    Assert.assertEquals("or", ListStackQueue.get(head, 1));
    Assert.assertEquals("not", ListStackQueue.get(head, 2));
    Assert.assertEquals("to", ListStackQueue.get(head, 3));
  }     

  @Test
  public void testRemoveNodes4() {
        String[] sentence = {"to", "be", "or", "not", "to", "be"};
        Node<String> head = ListStackQueue.buildList(sentence);
        head = ListStackQueue.removeNodes(head, "or");
        Assert.assertEquals(5, ListStackQueue.getLength(head));
        Assert.assertEquals("to", ListStackQueue.get(head, 0));
        Assert.assertEquals("be", ListStackQueue.get(head, 1));
        Assert.assertEquals("not", ListStackQueue.get(head, 2));
        Assert.assertEquals("to", ListStackQueue.get(head, 3));
        Assert.assertEquals("be", ListStackQueue.get(head, 4));
      }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting when running my code in Eclipse with JUnit test. This is the error for the testRemoveNodes2 test. There is no error for testRemoveNodes1 test.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<4> but was:<6>
```

Comment: Mr. Rabbit, where is your error output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using JUnit to run it in Eclipse and it gives me this error: 
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<4> but was:<6>

Comment: The logic in your `removeNodes()` method _appears_ to be correct.  Can you include the full code which consumes this method so that we may see how it is being used?

Comment: must use equals String comparison must use equals String comparison must use equals String comparison...

Comment: Sure, I have edited with my entire code and the given test code.

Comment: I've updated my code to use .equals, rather than == and !=. I'm getting the NullPointerException error and it points to this particular code in the test file:

head = ListStackQueue.removeNodes(head, "to");

Comment: @Mr.Rabbit You were **not** supposed to use equals on the Node references, back up! curr.equals(head) etc. etc.

Comment: And you must compare curr. **item** .equals(item), since curr references a Node and item refers to a String!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see your program wouldn't work is if the comparisons of `curr.data` and `item` using `==` and `!=` are not working as expected. Which is entirely possible, as comparing strings using these operators is not recommended, not a common practice, and unless you really know what you're doing (optimization), they will not do what you expected.

For example, if in your implementation of `ListStackQueue.buildList` you create the values of the `data` field of nodes using `new String(...)`. If you create the values that way, then `s1 == s2` will never be true for two strings, even if their values are the same.

The bottomline is, don't compare strings using `==` and `!=`,
rewrite your implementation to use `.equals` instead,
and then it should work.
Of course, when you do that, before calling `.equals` on an object, you need to first verify that it's not null, otherwise you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

Assuming that there are no nodes where the `data` field is `null`, this should work:

```
if (head == null) {
    System.out.println("list is empty");
} else {
    while (curr != null) {
        if (!curr.data.equals(item)) {
            prev = curr; 
            curr = curr.next; 
        } else if (curr == head) {
            head = head.next; 
            curr = curr.next; 
        } else if (curr != head && curr.next != null) {
            prev.next = curr.next; 
            curr = curr.next; 
        } else {
            curr.next = null; 
        }
    }   
}

return head;
```

I also dropped some redundant conditions.

If you want to allow `null` values for `Node.data`,
then the `!curr.data.equals(item)` above will be a bit more complicated,
replace it with:

```
        if (curr.data == null && item != null || curr.data != null && !curr.data.equals(item)) {
```

Comment: There's no way you can write buildList so that removeNodes as shown ans with the call in the test would work with == and !=. (Yes I know String.intern.)

Comment: So I should change all the == and != using the .equals even when comparing to null? Yes, I believe ListStackQueue.buildList creates new nodes values using String.

Comment: Yes, you should use equals for string comparisons. If the string on which you call it might be null, then you need to do a null-check first

Comment: It would very much depend on how the array for buildList was put together, not on the way the method was written.

Comment: @laune it would depend on both. There are several conceivable ways to screw this up

Comment: Screw up? If the list has `Node<T>` the usual understanding is to store the object references as list items. I don't see why `Node<String>` should make any difference. - Not using equals for String is "screwing up" (except in very peculiar circumstances).

Comment: I included the buildList code. I apologize for not including it earlier.

Comment: @MrRabbit thanks. Looking at it, it seems to me the comparison with `==` should have worked. It doesn't really matter though, because it's not the right way to compare strings in this particular talk, and in general. I explained in my answer, and provided the fix.